# System design to store matrices generated from different app servers in common place

Tags: soa, system-design

I was asked below high level system design question in Amazon interview this week. It was not clear to me so could not answer well. Can you please provide some answer on this?

There are some application servers that are generating matrices in the form of (key,value). Matrices generated in all these servers have same format but can be different size. We want to store these matrices in a single place so that queries can be performed on that machine. How can we store these matrices? Can we use service oriented architecture on this?

Answer (score 2):

you can use microservice architecture, where any service generating matrix will request one service which will be responsible for storing this matrices.

Mysql, as mentioned above, is good solution, but there need to be more specific. How big are this matrices? How many matricese can there be? How often will they be loaded (how many request per second)? What of type is key and value? What type of queries we talk about? And many many other questions. Despite on answsers to this questions you can select proper key-value storage.

The other goal is how to transfer this matrices to storage service. Is REST the best solution, or will we need use some pub-sub broker like kafka? For answering your question you need to be more specific, and this questions from your side is, in my opinion, that what the HR wanted listen from you on this interview, not details about implementation. Sometimes questions are the best answers :)

Comment: This answer, unlike mine, actually demonstrates relevant experience!
Mine would probably be enough to demonstrate basic software development experience and an a general engineering method. Junior vs. Senior answers :)

Answer (score 0):

You could save the matrices in a single DB table with the columns key, value, matrixID.

This way, you can just query for one matrix like this:

```
SELECT key, value FROM matrices WHERE matrixID = 1234
```

Or you could list all the matrices in your table like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT matrixID from matrices
```

So you have a simple, versatile setup.

And a tangent on interviews: In general, technical interviewers are looking for some ideas and problem solving skills, not necessarily knowledge from a "reputable" source.

So next time, just throw out some ideas, evaluate them and then choose one that might solve the problem in the best way. Do all of this aloud. It's not about the best possible answer, it's about the process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can we use service oriented architecture any concept here because interviewer told me use service oriented architecture to solve this problem?

Comment: Well, you can write all kinds of services to access the database, like accessing, modifying, adding matrices, so that the consumer doesnt have to know how to query your DB. I don't think there is much more to it. Maybe he wanted to check how well you know the principles of service-oriented architecture?

Answer (score 0):

***Backgroud***

This problem is more like a problem in the field of machine learning. Machine learning often uses a matrix of multi-dimensional features to describe the connections of the world.

---

***how matrix stores?***

***sparse vs dense matrix***

To make this model, you firstly need to consider how this thing is stored. According to some things I have learned, On many times your matrix is ​​not high-density. The industry term is called sparse matrix.

Many elements of sparse matrix are 0, so storing each element will lead to a lot of waste of space. Generally we will divide this large matrix into many small matrices, which not only reduces the storage cost, but the small matrix may have many duplicates. For these duplicate small matrices, you can save only one copy, and then reference it in many places.
The opposite side of a sparse matrix is ​​a compact matrix. A matrix of mxn elements can be understood as a combination of multiple one-dimensional vectors. In other words, a special matrix of vectors with m equal to 1. So you can fetch and store these matrices with a vector(for example in c++) container .

***various type***

Then the stored elements will be divided into int, float, string or sthm else types. The elements in the matrix are generally a common template type, so the storage also needs to consider what type of matrix description is used.

---

***SOA Api***

Let's talk about what aspects should be considered for service-oriented APIs.
What matrix you need to get and what key is similar to accessing a two-dimensional array, you need to specify i and j like `matrix[x][j]`.

Then for a large matrix, or a dynamically changing matrix. Different keys may be distributed on different servers, you need to provide a common implementation, you need to find the server location corresponding to the key. If you do batch search for multiple keys, of course the overall speed depends on the slowest shard key speed.

---

I have thought of so much for the time being, and if I have more thought, I will add it again. Hope it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't a "correct" answer to this question because the question is intentionally vague. The purpose of this question is to determine the seniority of a developer. A junior developer will jump straight in and try to design a system based on the given information. A more senior developer will start by asking clarifying questions:

How many matrices are we storing? How big are the individual matrices? What type of data is in the matrices? How are we querying the data? How many queries/second are we expecting?

All of these questions are important because the system you're designing depends on the throughput you need. So these questions will help you discover the actual requirements, and once you have them, you can go ahead and design the system.

What Amazon wanted from you was to first find the requirements and then come up with your best solution.

Comment: this is duplicate answer, you wrote exactly the same, as me few days ago

Comment: @michalpavlik I disagree. My answer is far from being "exactly the same", because it focuses on explaining the purpose of the interview question. You only touched upon this at the end when you wrote:
> this questions from your side is, in my opinion, that what the HR wanted listen from you on this interview, not details about implementation.